# Python can't find BBIO.GPIO library on Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gpio

I am trying to set up an Adafruit 'RGB backlight positive LCD 20x4'  using this tutorial:
https://learn.adafruit.com/character-lcd-with-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black/usage

When I go to the examples directory and run 'char_lcd_rgb.py', I get an error:
'ImportError: No module named Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO'

Why am I getting an error for a Beaglebone library on a Raspberry Pi?
Should I install BBIO.GPIO on the Raspberry or is there something wrong elsewhere?

[(Pi Version 3), (Python v 2.7.9)]

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem.  A function in Platform.py was not finding the string 'BCM2835' assuming my platform was a Beaglebone.

A kind user suggested that I re-install Adafruit_Python_GPIO as that includes code for the 4.9 kernel.